# How can I print the prediction from my model for an uploaded exemplar?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The TensorFlow course I have just completed gives the following example, but I would like to modify this to print the prediction for a categorical (rather than binary) exemplar. Currently my model has three categories: 0 (corresponding to '5'), 1 (corresponding to '10'), and 2 (corresponding to '20').

```
import numpy as np
from google.colab import files
from tensorflow.keras.utils import load_img, img_to_array

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
 
  path = '/content/' + fn
  img = load_img(path, target_size=(200, 150))
  x = img_to_array(img)
  x /= 255
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

  images = np.vstack([x])
  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
  print(classes[0])
  if classes[0]>0.5:
    print(fn + " is a human")
  else:
    print(fn + " is a horse")
```

I have tried junking together a complicated set of if functions, which led to the following error: `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

My junky if-statement looked like this:

```
if classes[0]=0:
    print(fn + " is a 5")
if classes[0]=1:
    print(fn + " is a 10")
if classes[0]=2:
    print(fn + " is a 20")
```

In hindsight, I am now realising that this method is fundamentally mistaken and what I want to do is print the highest number (i.e., the most probable category) in an array.

Taking a test, for example, I received the following output:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
[0.97390795 0.00138458 0.02470746]
```

I would to have a print statement functionally similar to that listed in the example code, but which selects the maximum value and prints the corresponding label along with its probability.

Answer (score 0):

[predict](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) returns an array of arrays.
Try this instead:

```py
if classes[0][0] == max(classes[0]):
    print(fn + " is a 5.")
elif classes[0][1] == max(classes[0]):
    print(fn + " is a 10")
elif classes[0][2] == max(classes[0]):
    print(fn + " is a 20")
```

Or in a cleaner way with a dictionnary:

```py
dic = {
    0 : 5,
    1 : 10,
    2 : 20
}

print(fn + " is a", dic[classes[0].argmax()])
```

Comment: Thank you, this has allowed me to junk together the following code which seems to work:

  if classes[0][0]>0.5:
    print(fn + " is a 5.")
  if classes[0][1]>0.5:
    print(fn + " is a 10")
  if classes[0][2]>0.5:
    print(fn + " is a 20")

Comment: There might not always be a value above 0.5, for example `[0.3, 0.3, 0.4]`. You should get the `max` value instead.